# Encryption key changes when application is restarted?

Tags: java, android, encryption, gson, aes

i am trying to encrypt some videos and then decrypting them later when required. the code works fine but since the key is generated randomly, if i encrypt a video and exit the application i wont be able to decrypt it again since next time when i open the application the keys are changed. I am using Gson to save my keys. but even that did not work.

The below is my encryption class code. Thanks in advance.

```
package com.example.videoplay;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class Encrypter { 
Context contxt;
File inFile;
File outFile;
File outFile_dec;
SecretKey key;
byte[] keyData;
SecretKey key2;
byte[] iv;
AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec;

private final static int IV_LENGTH = 16; // Default length with Default 128
                                            // key AES encryption 
private final static int DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

private final static String ALGO_RANDOM_NUM_GENERATOR = "SHA1PRNG";
private final static String ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR = "AES";
private final static String ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

public static String str_key,str_paramSpec,str_key2;

@SuppressWarnings("resource") 
public static void encrypt(SecretKey key, AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
    try { 
         byte[] iv = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 
         0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A, (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 
         0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A }; 
         paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); 
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        } 
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    } 
} 

@SuppressWarnings("resource") 
public static void decrypt(SecretKey key, AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec, InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
    try { 
         byte[] iv = new byte[] { (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 
         0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A, (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 
         0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A }; 
         paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv); 
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO_VIDEO_ENCRYPTOR);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        out = new CipherOutputStream(out, c);
        int count = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_READ_WRITE_BLOCK_BUFFER_SIZE];
        while ((count = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
        } 
    } finally { 
        out.close();
    } 
} 

    public Encrypter(Context ctx) {
    //      
    inFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +MainActivity.Directory+MainActivity.filename );
    outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + MainActivity.Directory+"/"+MainActivity.temponlyfilename);
    outFile_dec = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + MainActivity.Directory+MainActivity.filename);

    contxt=ctx;
    try { 

        //........................................................................................

        SharedPreferences  mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        String json = mPrefs.getString("pref_str_key", "empty");
        if(json.equalsIgnoreCase("empty"))
        {
            key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR).generateKey();

            keyData = key.getEncoded();
            key2 = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, 0, keyData.length, ALGO_SECRET_KEY_GENERATOR); //if you want to store key bytes to db so its just how to //recreate back key from bytes array

            iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
            SecureRandom.getInstance(ALGO_RANDOM_NUM_GENERATOR).nextBytes(iv); // If
                                                                                // storing 
                                                                                // separately 
            paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

            Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            str_key = gson.toJson(key);
            prefsEditor.putString("pref_str_key", str_key);
            str_key2 = gson.toJson(2);
            prefsEditor.putString("pref_str_key2", str_key2);
            prefsEditor.commit();

        }else
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            str_key = mPrefs.getString("pref_str_key", "");
            key = gson.fromJson(str_key, SecretKey.class);
            str_key2 = mPrefs.getString("pref_str_key2", "");
            key2 = gson.fromJson(str_key2, SecretKey.class);
        }
        //........................................................................................

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

public File Decrypt(File dir)
{
    File dirout = new File(dir.getParent()+"/temp.ts");
try {
    Encrypter.decrypt(key2, paramSpec, new FileInputStream(dir), new FileOutputStream(dirout));
    outFile_dec.delete();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
return dirout;
}

public File Encrypt(File dir) {
    File dirout = new File(dir.getParent()+"/temp.ts");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Encrypter.encrypt(key, paramSpec, new FileInputStream(dir), new FileOutputStream(dirout));
        dir.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return dirout;
}




public void DecryptFromTo(File dir,File dirout)
{

try {
    Encrypter.decrypt(key2, paramSpec, new FileInputStream(dir), new FileOutputStream(dirout));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

}



}
```

Comment: Way too much code - we are not here to debug for you. Try testing your key storage and retrieval separately - does this return the same data? If not, show us only that code.

Comment: Just check the code inside the try block of  "Encrypter(Context ctx)" method that's where i am saving the keys and retrieving them

Comment: Remember that the people helping you here are doing so in their spare time, for fun. Why make it difficult for us? Show us you've taken some effort yourself - for instance, you've completely ignored part of my question which was "*Try testing your key storage and retrieval separately - does this return the same data?*".

Comment: Yes, Both storage and retrieval returns the same Json String, I feel that i have missed out to store some other object apart from the two keys. But i am unable to find that out. is there a way to manually give a key in the above code.

Comment: You can try a static key by using `new SecretKeySpec(<key data>, "AES")`. You could even use `new byte[16]` as your test key data.

Comment: @user3482497 I think its `paramSpec` which is changing on App restart not your key.

Answer (score 1):

For temporary solution, I think it is better for you to use the static key as suggested by the Duncan. Because even though the new key is generated every time, if you store the key in the plain JSON file for next usage, what would be so different than keep it in the code and reuse it over again? If anyone is trying to get the key and decrypt the video, he/she would have to either debug/de-assemble the code to find the static key or just look at the application directory for plain JSON key file, which both are not much difficult tasks.

If you really care about the security(I guess that's the reason that you are trying to encrypt the video stream at the first place) I suggest you to look at the [Android Keystore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) and try to encrypt and store your video encryption key with user's PIN or passphrase that can be provided from user-side.